# Full-width image content in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i want to use the following image gallery: http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/index2.html

the technical part worked, but i can´t use the full width in the wordpress content-area.
Here is the link: http://jga-versand.de/startseite_neu/

I use the visual composer. There i can tell "stretch Row and Content" but it don´t work.

Maybe someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: You should either add some of the code or post this question in Wordpress Development http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ viel Glück

Comment: It seems that you're using default page template which container div is set to max width of 1200px, if you've a full width page template try to use it it should resolve the problem.

You can try yourself to workaround this using css
`.container {
    width: 100%;
}`

but it will cause the whole page view to be full width including navigation menu, logo, footer, and breadcrumbs.